# Vercel Serverless function error Parsing JSON

Tags: next.js, serverless, vercel

I am having trouble with vercel serverless functions, in that I am getting the following error:

artwork route hit!

```
error SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse ()
at parseJSONFromBytes (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6571:19)
at successSteps (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6545:27)
at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1211:60
at node:internal/process/task_queues:140:7
at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:203:9)
at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:137:8)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

This error occurs at an attempt to call await req.json() within a route handler of a next project (app router, /api folder).

These routes work fine on my local machine, and the request is being sent in the correct format. I have this app deployed as a long running service on another platform, and there are no issues when I route requests there either - This leads me to believe that there is an issue with my vercel setup.

```js
// imports..
export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
    console.log("artwork route hit!"); // this is logged
    
    if (!req.body) {
        console.log("no body found") // this is not logged
        return new NextResponse("No request body found", { status: 401 }); 
    }

    const job: Job = await req.json();
    console.log(`new job parsed: ${job.id}`) // this is not logged
```

As mentioned, this error only occurs in the vercel function. locally, and deployed elsewhere, the code runs as expected (body is found, function can parse it and move on). As such, I am having difficulty diagnosing why specifically this runtime is having trouble with req.json().

I can note as well that the middleware from the Next project fires before these requests successfully. I wonder if they may be stripping the body somehow? Again though I am finding this hard to diagnose as the setup is identical to node in localhost and hosted online with no trouble.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you share the `CURL` of how you call the vercel POST api?